# How to mark a float as inline?

Tags: tables, multicol

I need to insert a a narrow but tall table. To save space, I would like the other half of the page to be occupied by text.

At first, I succeeded using using package `multicol` together with `tabular` environment. However, if I add some text at the beginning of the page, the table gets trimmed to the bottom of the page! In the below example, the table reaches only 27, instead of 30. Adding more text at the start of the page cuts the table even shorter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}     % For coloured rows within tables.
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.
Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.
Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.
Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.
Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.
Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.
Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.
Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.
Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.
Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.
Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.
Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.
Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.
Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.
Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.
Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.
Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.
Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.
Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.
Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.
Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.
\begin{multicols}{2}  % Some bug apparently prevents multicols from working with tabular.
\rowcolors{1}{white}{lightgray}
\begin{tabular}{l | c | c | c}
Row& *1/2 & *2/3 & *1    \\
1  & d-3  & d-3  & d-2   \\
2  & d-3  & d-2  & d-1   \\
3  & d-2  & d-1  & d-1   \\
4  & d-2  & d-1  & d+1   \\
5  & d-1  & d    & d+2   \\
6  & d-1  & d    & d+3   \\
7  & d    & d+1  & 2d    \\
8  & d+1  & d+2  & 2d+1  \\
9  & d+1  & 2d-1 & 2d+2  \\
10 & d+2  & 2d   & 3d    \\
11 & d+2  & 2d   & 3d+1  \\
12 & 2d-1 & 2d+1 & 3d+2  \\
13 & 2d-1 & 2d+2 & 3d+3  \\
14 & 2d   & 3d-1 & 4d    \\
15 & 2d+1 & 3d   & 4d+1  \\
16 & 2d+1 & 3d+1 & 4d+2  \\
17 & 2d+2 & 3d+1 & 5d    \\
18 & 2d+2 & 3d+2 & 5d+1  \\
19 & 3d-1 & 4d-1 & 5d+2  \\
20 & 3d-1 & 4d   & 5d+3  \\
21 & 3d   & 4d   & 6d    \\
22 & 3d+1 & 4d+1 & 6d+1  \\
23 & 3d+1 & 4d+2 & 6d+2  \\
24 & 3d+2 & 5d-1 & 7d    \\
25 & 3d+2 & 6d   & 7d+1  \\
26 & 4d-1 & 5d   & 7d+2  \\
27 & 4d-1 & 5d+1 & 7d+3  \\
28 & 4d   & 5d+2 & 8d    \\
29 & 4d+1 & 6d-1 & 8d+1  \\
30 & 4d+1 & 6d   & 8d+2
\end{tabular}
Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.
Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.
Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.
Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.
Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.
Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.
Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.
Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.
Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.
Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.
Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.
Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.
Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.
Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.
Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.
Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.
Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.
Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.
Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.
Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.
Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you mean "a narrow but tall table"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `wraptable` from `wrapfigure`-package but you would have to place the table manualy.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}     % For coloured rows within tables.
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\begin{document}
Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.
Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.
Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.
Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.
Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.
Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.
Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.
Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.
Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.

\begin{wraptable}{l}{5.5cm}
\rowcolors{1}{white}{lightgray}
\begin{tabular}{l | c | c | c}
Row& *1/2 & *2/3 & *1    \\
1  & d-3  & d-3  & d-2   \\
2  & d-3  & d-2  & d-1   \\
3  & d-2  & d-1  & d-1   \\
4  & d-2  & d-1  & d+1   \\
5  & d-1  & d    & d+2   \\
6  & d-1  & d    & d+3   \\
7  & d    & d+1  & 2d    \\
8  & d+1  & d+2  & 2d+1  \\
9  & d+1  & 2d-1 & 2d+2  \\
10 & d+2  & 2d   & 3d    \\
11 & d+2  & 2d   & 3d+1  \\
12 & 2d-1 & 2d+1 & 3d+2  \\
13 & 2d-1 & 2d+2 & 3d+3  \\
14 & 2d   & 3d-1 & 4d    \\
15 & 2d+1 & 3d   & 4d+1  \\
16 & 2d+1 & 3d+1 & 4d+2  \\
17 & 2d+2 & 3d+1 & 5d    \\
18 & 2d+2 & 3d+2 & 5d+1  \\
19 & 3d-1 & 4d-1 & 5d+2  \\
20 & 3d-1 & 4d   & 5d+3  \\
21 & 3d   & 4d   & 6d    \\
22 & 3d+1 & 4d+1 & 6d+1  \\
23 & 3d+1 & 4d+2 & 6d+2  \\
24 & 3d+2 & 5d-1 & 7d    \\
25 & 3d+2 & 6d   & 7d+1  \\
26 & 4d-1 & 5d   & 7d+2  \\
27 & 4d-1 & 5d+1 & 7d+3  \\
28 & 4d   & 5d+2 & 8d    \\
29 & 4d+1 & 6d-1 & 8d+1  \\
30 & 4d+1 & 6d   & 8d+2
\end{tabular}
\end{wraptable}

Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.
Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.
Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.
Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.
Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.
Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.
Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.
Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.
Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.
Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.
Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.
Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.
Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.
Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.
Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.
Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.
Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.
Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.
Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.
Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.
Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's great. [Here](http://ctan.org/pkg/wrapfig) is a link to the package download and documentation for ease of reference.